# Removing non red toned pixels

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have a very simple image processing application.

> I am trying to remove the pixels which
>   do not involve red tones.

So far a basic code seems to achieve what I want.

```
        private void removeUnRedCellsBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte threshold = Convert.ToByte(diffTxtBox.Text); 
            byte r, g, b;
            for (int i = 0; i < m_Bitmap.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m_Bitmap.Height; j++)
                {
                    r = im_matrix[i, j].R;
                    g = im_matrix[i, j].G;
                    b = im_matrix[i, j].B;
                    if ((r - b) < threshold || (r - g) < threshold)
                    {
                        m_Bitmap.SetPixel(i, j, Color.White);
                    }

                }
            }
            pictureArea_PictureBox.Image = m_Bitmap;
        }
```

Basically if the difference of (red and blue) or (red and green) is less than a threshold it sets the pixel to white.

> My results seems to be promising
>   however I am wondering if  there is a
>   better    solution for determining
>   whether a pixel involves red tones in
>   it.

My results for a threshold value of 75 is [image: before] [image: after]

Any algorithm or thought will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance

[image: matlab imtool]

Comment: I think the term "red tone" is a bit subjective, but i would guess it would be sufficient to check for the red amount beeing above a certain threshold.

Comment: So should I check just the r value of a pixel ?

Comment: Thats what i would do when i want to get pixels with a "red tone"

Comment: Would you consider yellow or orange to be red tones?

Comment: Your algorithm seems to be valid and you don't suggest that there's a particular problem with your output (though without seeing what the input is, it's hard to judge).  Is there a problem that you're having that you need help with?

Comment: Dan Puzey I just wonder if there is a better solution. To Jan as you can see from the imtool of matlab just checking the r value of a pixel does not work for me.

Comment: Actually my input is the first picture and the output is the second picture there circles are removed the third is from imtool of matlab Thanks for your attentions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might have more luck if you convert the RGB values to a different color space, like HSL or HSV. Check out [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) on Wikipedia. Converting a pixel to one of those color spaces should help you isolate the hue, which is what you're mostly concerned with.

Comment: .NET code for converting to HSV: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2006/04/12/575476.aspx

Comment: You'll also need to consider the saturation and lightness, even in the new color space - judging by hue alone is not enough.